# How to directly bind xaml's FontIcon element to modelView's FontIcon element

Tags: c#, mvvm, model-binding

I would like to directly bind the xaml FontIcon element to viewmodel FontIcon element.

Now I do it like this

```
<FontIcon  
    FontFamily="{x:Bind FontIcon.FontFamily}" 
    Glyph="{x:Bind FontIcon.Glyph}" 
    Foreground="{x:Bind FontIcon.Foreground}"/>
```

binding to

```
public FontIcon FontIcon { get; set; }
```

I would like to do it like this

```
<FontIcon "{x:Bind FontIcon}" />
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. Normally you don't create an element in a view model. Instead you should have the three values: FontFamily, Glyph (code) and Foreground color as properties in the view model and then bind directly to these  properties.